# Javascript datePicker Controller: Hard Coded string working, variable not

Tags: javascript

I'm using a datePicker that can be found here:

http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2011/10/11/unobtrusive-accessible-datepicker-widgit-v6

I have it working fine, as long as I hard code the id of the object. i.e.

```
var newid = "date" + maxidOnce.toString();
        datePickerController.createDatePicker({                           
            formElements:{"date1":"%Y-%m-%d"},
            statusFormat:"%l, %d %F %Y", 
            noFadeEffect:true
        });
```

However if I replace the id with the variable, it no longer works. I don't see how there is any difference.

```
var newid = "oncedate" + maxidOnce.toString();
        datePickerController.createDatePicker({                           
            formElements:{newid:"%Y-%m-%d"},
            statusFormat:"%l, %d %F %Y", 
            noFadeEffect:true
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't see how there is any difference.

The difference is that JavaScript object **keys are not interpreted as variables** when using [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals). Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead.

```
var newid = "oncedate" + maxidOnce;
var formElts = {};
formElts[newid] = "%Y-%m-%d";
datePickerController.createDatePicker({                           
    formElements: formElts,
    statusFormat: "%l, %d %F %Y", 
    noFadeEffect: true
});

// or, to write it another way,
var newid = "oncedate" + maxidOnce;
var options = {                           
    formElements: {},
    statusFormat: "%l, %d %F %Y", 
    noFadeEffect: true
};
options.formElements[newid] = "%Y-%m-%d";
datePickerController.createDatePicker(options);
```

Comment: Sure enough, I've clearly got some more learning to do. Thanks for the quick response.